# how to create boot partition on nonpartitioned disk?

Tags: boot, partition, gparted, partition-table

how to create boot partition on new nonpartitioned disk? UEFI boot,for Linux, single OS on disk. Preferably using GParted.

Comment: Do you have an existing installation and you want to move the boot partition to a new drive or just preparing the disk for a new installation?

Comment: Preparing new disk for new installation.

Comment: Do not confuse an ESP - efi system partition formatted FAT32 & required for UEFI boot with /boot which must be Linux formatted often ext4. ESP is more equivalent to the MBR as it is where booting starts. But a /boot partition is where most of grub & kernels are. Except of course for systemD boot which puts more of /boot into ESP.  But most desktops do not need a separate partition for /boot. Just keep it as a folder in / (root). UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: @oldfred is it recommended to have a separate /boot partition on laptop? If its helpful, should it be created in the first step `/boot ext4 500M`, and then to create `/boot/efi esp (fat32) 250M`?

Comment: Most desktops do not need /boot as a partition. ESP should be 300 to 500 MB unless installing on a small drive. If I put a full install on my 64GB flash drive I use 100MB for ESP. But do not plan on lots of installs or special needs for larger ESP.  I do like to separate system from data. Or / (root) from /home or if /home inside / have separate data partition for most data.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on distribution you are installing, you don't need to prepare the disk at all -- installers are usually able to partition the drive themselves.

But if you want to do it manually, you can simply create a new partition table in GParted (*Device → Create partition table*), you'll want to add *gpt* partition table on an EFI system and then you can add partitions you want. 100 MiB is recommended size for [EFI boot partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) but it can be bigger (set flag to `esp` after creating it), 1 GiB is enough for `/boot` (you don't need a separate `/boot` partition but it doesn't hurt to have one) and then add `/`, `/home` and swap partitions. `ext4` is usually the default choice for filesystem. `/` should be at least 50 GiB and swap around twice the size of your RAM (but more than 8 or 16 GiB is usually too much and not really useful if you don't plan suspending the system to disk).

Comment: namely, manual partitioning. So first should be created esp partition100Mb ( fat32), then should be created /boot partition 1Gb?(ext4 ?) what's difference between them?